# How to call command program in MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab

In MATLAB it is possible to call command programs written in C or C++. For example, I can use the following command to call a command program in Windows:

```
system('program.exe -i input_file1.txt -o output_file1.txt -m 1 ');
```

By doing so, I can invoke command line program directly from MATLAB. The problem I have now is that all the arguments must be fixed when I use the `system` function. If one argument, for example, is  changeable, then using `system` function will fail.  For instance,

```
for i=1:3
  input_file_name = [num2str(i),'.txt'];
  system('program.exe -i input_file_name -o output_file1.txt -m 1 ');
end
```

Then, how can I deal with this situation? Thanks.

Comment: I don't have Matlab installed on my system right now but giving it a try. What is the error being displayed? Run `whos` on the `input_file_name` and see what's the type of the variable. If required you could try `strcat()`. Essentially make sure it's a `string` type being input to `system` command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change your syntax slightly:

```
for i=1:3
  input_file_name = [num2str(i),'.txt'];
  system(['program.exe -i ' input_file_name ' -o output_file1.txt -m 1 ']);
end
```

`input_file_name` is the name of your variable in MATLAB so you can write verbatim in the string you pass to the `system` command.

Answer (score 3):

More generally you can use `sprintf` to construct strings to pass to `system`, for example something like:

```
for n=1:3  
   system(sprintf('program.exe -i %d.txt -o output%d.txt -m 1',n,n));
end
```

(avoid [using i and j as variables in MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/variable-names.html))